# Detect if scroll has touched bottom of page

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the code that I have been using to detect if a user has reached the bottom of the page by scrolling.

It's working fine in Chrome, Safari and Firefox, but in IE8 when the scrolling reaches at bottom of page, the showNextItems function is called twice. Can anyone pinpoint why, and how to fix it?

```
        $(window).scroll(function() {            
            if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == getDocHeight()) {
                if ($('#digitalContent p:hidden').size() > 0) {
                    getAjaxLoader($('.loader'), false);
                    getAjaxLoader($('.loader'), true);
                    window.setTimeout(function() {                      
                          getAjaxLoader($('.loader'), false);    

                              showNextItems('');

                    }, 1500);
                }
            }
        });


function getDocHeight() {
    var D = document;
    return Math.max(
        D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight,
        D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight,
        D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
function isBottom(m, wh) {
    if (m === "init") {
        if (wh === "off") $(window).off("scroll.isBottom");
        else if (wh === "on") {
            $(window).on("scroll.isBottom", function () {
                console.log(isBottom("scroll"));
            });
        }
    } else if (m === "scroll") {
        var isIt = $(document).height() - ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) <= 0;
        isBottom("init", "off");
        setTimeout(function () {
            isBottom("init", "on");
        }, 100);
        return isIt;
    }
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    isBottom("init", "on");
});
```

### Demo:

Should log `true` in IE8 only if at the bottom of the page.

```js
function isBottom(m, wh) {
 if (m === "init") {
  if (wh === "off") $(window).off("scroll.isBottom");
  else if (wh === "on") {
   $(window).on("scroll.isBottom", function () {
    console.log(isBottom("scroll"));
   });
  }
 } else if (m === "scroll") {
  var isIt = $(document).height() - ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) <= 0;
  isBottom("init", "off");
  setTimeout(function () {
   isBottom("init", "on");
  }, 100);
  return isIt;
 }
}
$(document).ready(function () {
 isBottom("init", "on");
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 2000px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: same issue with your code my function is being called twice. This issue is only being occurred on IE8

Comment: What if you attach it to the `mousewheel` event instead? `$(window).on("mousewheel", function() {`

Comment: Then what about touch devices. Will it work on those??

Comment: Yeah, you are right, it won't, but I would be surprised that any mobile devices would use IE8! So perhaps, if mousewheel works fine on IE8, you could try to detect IE8 and only bind your function to mousewheel for IE8 and to scroll event for the rest.

Comment: Hey, I improved my answer to remove the event listener after it fires once and reattach it within a `setTimeout()` function and it seems to work perfectly on IE8. Of course, this won't work on other browsers (cuz `scroll` will fire only once), but you can sniff which browser it is and call the appropriate function.

Comment: Actually i solved it my my self. The issue was with setTimeout. It was not being cleared in IE8. So i just cleared it before calling showNextItems() and it solved my issue. Any way thanks for the help.